# I am not able to test my application

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to test my application in my emulator but I don't ever see my application appear on it.

My manifest file contains the following code in the activity portion of AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Here is a screenshot of my nexus 4 emulator:

[image]

I am currently unsure what could be the reason why my application is not showing up. Would anyone have any idea? I want to avoid testing it on my phone thank you. I made another application and it was running well on my phone and now, I added few files I found on the internet, the application disappeared? (Also modified)

Any help is much appreciated!

My MainActivity code:

```
    package com.eatwithme;

/*
 * Copyright (C) 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 *  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 *  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 *  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.eatwithme.activities.SampleActivityBase;
import com.eatwithme.logger.Log;
import com.eatwithme.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;



public class MainActivity extends SampleActivityBase
        implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    /**
     * GoogleApiClient wraps our service connection to Google Play Services and provides access
     * to the user's sign in state as well as the Google's APIs.
     */
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private PlaceAutocompleteAdapter mAdapter;

    private AutoCompleteTextView mAutocompleteView;
    private TextView mPlaceDetailsText;

    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_GREATER_SYDNEY = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-34.041458, 150.790100), new LatLng(-33.682247, 151.383362));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set up the Google API Client if it has not been initialised yet.
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            rebuildGoogleApiClient();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Retrieve the AutoCompleteTextView that will display Place suggestions.
        mAutocompleteView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_places);

        // Register a listener that receives callbacks when a suggestion has been selected
        mAutocompleteView.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);

        // Retrieve the TextView that will display details of the selected place.
        mPlaceDetailsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_details);

        // Set up the adapter that will retrieve suggestions from the Places Geo Data API that cover
        // the entire world.
        mAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                BOUNDS_GREATER_SYDNEY, null);
        mAutocompleteView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Set up the 'clear text' button that clears the text in the autocomplete view
        Button clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_clear);
        clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAutocompleteView.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Listener that handles selections from suggestions from the AutoCompleteTextView that
     * displays Place suggestions.
     * Gets the place id of the selected item and issues a request to the Places Geo Data API
     * to retrieve more details about the place.
     *
     * @see com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataApi#getPlaceById(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,
     * String...)
     */
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener
            = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            /*
             Retrieve the place ID of the selected item from the Adapter.
             The adapter stores each Place suggestion in a PlaceAutocomplete object from which we
             read the place ID.
              */
            final PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mAdapter.getItem(position);
            final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
            Log.i(TAG, "Autocomplete item selected: " + item.description);

            /*
             Issue a request to the Places Geo Data API to retrieve a Place object with additional
              details about the place.
              */
            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                    .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
            placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked: " + item.description,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "Called getPlaceById to get Place details for " + item.placeId);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Callback for results from a Places Geo Data API query that shows the first place result in
     * the details view on screen.
     */
    private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
            = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                // Request did not complete successfully
                Log.e(TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " + places.getStatus().toString());

                return;
            }
            // Get the Place object from the buffer.
            final Place place = places.get(0);

            // Format details of the place for display and show it in a TextView.
            mPlaceDetailsText.setText(formatPlaceDetails(getResources(), place.getName(),
                    place.getId(), place.getAddress(), place.getPhoneNumber(),
                    place.getWebsiteUri()));

            Log.i(TAG, "Place details received: " + place.getName());
        }
    };

    private static Spanned formatPlaceDetails(Resources res, CharSequence name, String id,
                                              CharSequence address, CharSequence phoneNumber, Uri websiteUri) {
        Log.e(TAG, res.getString(R.string.place_details, name, id, address, phoneNumber,
                websiteUri));
        return Html.fromHtml(res.getString(R.string.place_details, name, id, address, phoneNumber,
                websiteUri));

    }


    /**
     * Construct a GoogleApiClient for the {@link Places#GEO_DATA_API} using AutoManage
     * functionality.
     * This automatically sets up the API client to handle Activity lifecycle events.
     */
    protected synchronized void rebuildGoogleApiClient() {
        // When we build the GoogleApiClient we specify where connected and connection failed
        // callbacks should be returned, which Google APIs our app uses and which OAuth 2.0
        // scopes our app requests.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Called when the Activity could not connect to Google Play services and the auto manager
     * could resolve the error automatically.
     * In this case the API is not available and notify the user.
     *
     * @param connectionResult can be inspected to determine the cause of the failure
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

        // TODO(Developer): Check error code and notify the user of error state and resolution.
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Could not connect to Google API Client: Error " + connectionResult.getErrorCode(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Disable API access in the adapter because the client was not initialised correctly.
        mAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(null);

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // Successfully connected to the API client. Pass it to the adapter to enable API access.
        mAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(mGoogleApiClient);
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected.");

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        // Connection to the API client has been suspended. Disable API access in the client.
        mAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(null);
        Log.e(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended.");
    }

}
```

My activity_main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
  Copyright (C) 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.

   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
   You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
  -->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/horizontal_page_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/horizontal_page_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/vertical_page_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/vertical_page_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/intro_message"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/autocomplete_hint"
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete_places"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/clear_text"
        android:id="@+id/button_clear"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/selected_place" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text=""
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:id="@+id/place_details" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=""
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:id="@+id/place_attribution" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I am developing using Android Studio and I am using Nexus 4 Emulator.

There are two logs

Log 1:

```
Creating filesystem with parameters:
Size: 69206016
Block size: 4096
Blocks per group: 32768
Inodes per group: 4224
Inode size: 256
Journal blocks: 1024
Label: 
Blocks: 16896
Block groups: 1
Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: device fd:792
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 40 81 335 557
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
```

Log 2 (Event Log):

```
  4:37:59 PM Gradle build finished in 55 sec
4:39:07 PM Gradle build finished in 8 sec
4:40:41 PM Gradle build finished in 11 sec
4:41:53 PM Gradle build finished in 23 sec
```

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.eatwithme"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

    <!-- PlacePicker also requires OpenGL ES version 2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxunLE"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Which emulator are you using? What IDE are you using? Do you have errors in your LogCat? Or in your Console?

Comment: Ill add that detail to my post. Thank you for pointing it out to me that the information is significant to the community

Comment: I added the manifest! :) From previously what I have read on stackoverflow it is the activity portion which is important only to the running application but regardless, I post the entire file.

Comment: Do you know any information I should remove from my post to avoid confusion to future users?

Comment: yes the manifest is the only important thing,  quick question are you certain it installs? is the min sdk version the same or higher on the device you testing? jibberish questions, i know

Comment: The emulator running was API 22. If that makes any sense...whereas my manifest says android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"

Comment: Are you able to run your application on the emulator and test manually anything?